# Managing multiple iOS authentication Firebase - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, fbsdk

I have a question concerning adding multiple authentication methods to the iOS application.

Some authentication Systems (such as `Facebook` and `Google`) need to return boolean values in the method:

`func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

for Google I need to return:

`return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url) ?? true`

and for Facebook auth I need to return:

`return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)`

If I return one boolean, the other will never be called.

How can I check if the user is logging in with one particular method and return the right boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url) {
  return true
}
else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) {
  return true
}
return false
```

FirebaseUI follows a similar approach - it loops through all available / activated authentication providers, checking for each of them if it is able to handle the URL, and returning `true` if that's the case. Check out their [implementation](https://cs.opensource.google/firebase-sdk/FirebaseUI-iOS/+/master:Auth/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIAuth.m;l=115).